# angularJS ng-attr- expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

hello i am working on a navigation direction.
if there are any child entries i have to add a attribute "uib-dropdown"

```
<li ng-attr-uib-dropdown="{{!!tree[$index].children ? '' : undefined }}" ng-repeat="nav in tree" ng-class="{ 'active' : isActive(nav.path) }">
```

the variable "!!tree[$index].children" would return true or false.
i am behind google now since 2hours but i cannot see how to use this expression with ng-attr the right way.

because now its adding the uib-dropdown to every li. doesn´t matter if it is true or false.

i hope someone can help me. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Because our answer for `tree[$index].children` can be truthy, if `tree[$index].children` has an answer, it will be true, if it's empty or undefined, then it will be false/falsey. There is no need for the `!!` or the ternary operator.</strike>

`<li ng-attr-uib-dropdown="{{tree[$index].children}}">`
You could also use the `||` (or operator) to better illustrate "falsey" of undefined.
`<li ng-attr-uib-dropdown="{{tree[$index].children || undefined}}">`

---

Created a [plunkit](http://plnkr.co/WPvTfHvGA77q9WUIMmaH). Here I used `ng-if` where if the array "food" exist, then allow the dropdown. If you remove the "food" array, the link is replaced without the dropdown.

```
<a href ng-if="!food">
    Click me, no dropdown, yo!
</a>

<!-- Simple dropdown -->
<span ng-if="food" uib-dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
    <a href id="simple-dropdown" uib-dropdown-toggle>
        Click me for a dropdown, yo!
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
        <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
            <a href>{{choice}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Comment: Hello, first thank you for your answer. i understand it now a little bit better :)

But its still not working:
also if i add a scope variable which does nit exists, its still shown and calls the directive (can see it because that one adds automatically a class)
ng-attr-uib-dropdown="{{asdasdas}}"

any ideas what there can be still wrong?

Comment: @Patrick - I've added a new solution the day before. Won't `ng-if` work for you?